# Google map grid loading, but not showing the map

Tags: android

In my android application ,I try to  use Google map .Then i get  key from  shacode. i followed this  tutorial  to get Api key  visit http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/tag/google-maps-api-key/   And  I  used  my key in project  Android  manifest.xml.

This is my code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="6"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.Api_key"
            android:value="MyGooglekey" />    
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share your code here?

Comment: Yes   i was added my code above .

Comment: Is that all the code you have in your application?

Comment: i followed this   http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/using-google-maps-in-android-development-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded follow links  and  i solve this matter.Thank you all.This  Tutorial explained  A-Z  path to  solve this  problem.follow  link 1;

Another thing is  Now  can used  android studio  it is  more than easy
can be  follow this tutorials.follow  link 2;

http://www.todroid.com/how-to-create-a-google-map-application-using-android-studio/

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/